# WPF: add Combobox into GridViewColumn Header

Tags: wpf, styles

So inside `ListView.View` i have this `Style` than i am using in order to remove `Header` borders:

```
<GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewHeaderDefaultStyle}">

</GridView>
```

**Style**

```
<Style x:Key="ListViewHeaderDefaultStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                    <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource GridViewColumnHeaderBorderBrushColor}" Background="Transparent">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="ContentHeader"
                                   Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                   Padding="0,5,0,0"
                                   Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                                   TextAlignment="Left"
                                   FontSize="13"
                                   Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource GridViewColumnHeaderForegroundColor}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{DynamicResource applicationFontFamily}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{DynamicResource GridViewColumnHeaderFontSize}"/>
    </Style>
```

And inside my `Column Header` i want to add `Combobox`:

```
<GridViewColumn Width="100" CellTemplate="{StaticResource ComboBoxDataTemplate}">
          <GridViewColumn.Header>
                   <StackPanel>
                       <ComboBox Width="90"
                                 SelectedIndex="0"
                                 SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged"
                                 Margin="0,0,0,0">
                                 <ComboBoxItem Content="   -- Select --"/>
                                 <ComboBoxItem Content="File"/>
                                 <ComboBoxItem Content="Name"/>
                                 </ComboBox>
                    </StackPanel>
          </GridViewColumn.Header>
```

But because my `Style` that i am using contains `TextBlock` i cannot see this `Combobox`.
If i removed the `Style` `ListViewHeaderDefaultStyle` this works fine but then all my `Header borders` that i want to remove `visible` again.

How can i use this `style` and also display my `Header` `Combobox` ?

Answer (score 0):

try this style

```
   <Style x:Key="ListViewHeaderDefaultStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                    <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource GridViewColumnHeaderBorderBrushColor}" Background="Transparent">
                        <Grid>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="ContentHeader"
                               Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                               Padding="0,5,0,0"
                               Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                               TextAlignment="Left"
                               FontSize="13"
                               Margin="5,0,0,0">
                                <TextBlock.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ContentPresenter}" Value="{x:Null}">
                                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </TextBlock.Style>
                            </TextBlock>
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource GridViewColumnHeaderForegroundColor}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{DynamicResource applicationFontFamily}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{DynamicResource GridViewColumnHeaderFontSize}"/>
    </Style>
```